# How to convert R dataframe to Json in name/value pair?

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

I have the following R data frame:

```
        Values
Type1   123
Type2   4565
Type3   7812
```

I expect the JSON output to be

```
{"Type1":123, "Type2":4565, "Type3":7812}
```

The number field can w/wo quote

I used jsonlite toJSON, the output is:

```
[{"Values":123,"_row":"Type1"}, 
 {"Values": 4565,"_row":"Type2"}, 
 {"Values": 7812,"_row":"Type3"}]
```

Comment: Seems different, in my case, the row names are dynamic.

Comment: Try `toJSON(as.list(setNames(df$Values,rownames(df))),auto_unbox=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution using [`rjson`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rjson/versions/0.2.15):**

```
df <- data.frame(Values = c(123, 4565, 7812))
rownames(df) <- paste0("Type", 1:3)

library(rjson)
toJSON(setNames(df$Values, rownames(df)))

[1] "{\"Type1\":123,\"Type2\":4565,\"Type3\":7812}"
```

Comment: Seems jsonlite drop the name in the same "toJSON" command. I will try to use rjson then.

Comment: BTW, the string can convert back to data frame using t(fromJSON("{\"Type1\":123,\"Type2\":4565,\"Type3\":7812}"))

Answer (score 2):

`jsonlite` is actually preserving your data structure, i.e., keeping your **rownames** (`Type1`, `Type2`, `Type3`).

Anyway, using jsonlite you could get the same behaviour with:

```
> jsonlite::toJSON(df %>% t() %>% tibble::as_data_frame())
[{"Type1":123,"Type2":4565,"Type3":7812}]
```

Please realize that with this solution you will lose the original column name `Values`. If the row names are important but not the column name, you should think about defining your data in a different way, as dealing with `rownames` can get [messy](http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/06/16/never-trust-the-row-names-of-a-dataframe-in-R/). You can add the Type as a second column or transpose your data -- one row, as many columns as types.